# Xamarin - CollectionView bind on ObservableCollection issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, uicollectionview, observablecollection

I'm experiencing a really strange issue trying to print an observableCollection of object in a CollectionView. I want to have a grid of 42 block and in each one print a number from 1 to 42. When I click on a block, I want its background to turn green.

Here is my code (pretty simple) :

Model :

```
public class Case
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ColorToPrint { get; set; }

        public Case(int id, string color)
        {
            Id = id;
            ColorToPrint = color;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel :

```
public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }
        public GridViewModel() 
        {
            Cases = new ObservableCollection<Case>();
            for (int i=1; i<=42; i++)
            {
                Case c = new Case(i, "Grey");
                Cases.Add(c);
            }

            SelectionChangedCommand = new Command(OnSelectionChanged);

        }

        private void OnSelectionChanged()
        {
            Case c = new Case(SelectedCase.Id, "Green");
            Cases[SelectedCase.Id - 1] = c;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Case> cases;
        public ObservableCollection<Case> Cases
        {
            get => cases;
            set
            {
                cases = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cases));
            }
        }

        private Case selectedCase;
        public Case SelectedCase
        {
            get => selectedCase;
            set
            {
                selectedCase = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCase));
            }
        }
    }
```

And my page :

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Cases}"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCase}"
                            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 6"
                            Margin="20">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    
                    <Frame Padding="2"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Frame BorderColor="Black"
                                MinimumHeightRequest="20"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                BackgroundColor="{Binding ColorToPrint}">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="15"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   />
                        </Frame>
                        
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
```

Of course, on my page.cs the viewmodel is define as the bindingContext.

So this code is working pretty well but I got a strange behaviour erasing the number in a block if I click on it (color change well) and reapearing if I click on another block. It seems also that this behaviour is happing ramdomly and not all time.

I've been lokking for a solution for my entire afternoon and I would really appreciate a bit of help on that.

Thanks everyone and excuse my pretty bad english ..

Tried different way of updating my observablecollection and also a lot of things with the propertychange event

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of Case instead of updating the existing instance?

Comment: I was just to be sure it wan't a problem of ObservableCollection not updating on update a member so I replace this by adding a new instance but same issue. Initialy I did it like that :

`{ Cases[SelectedCase.Id - 1] = SelectedCase;}`

and also like that :

`{ Cases[SelectedCase.Id - 1].ColorToPrint = "Green";}`

But same bug on all those combinaisons

Comment: You might need to play with the caching settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be replicated on my side. To fix the issue, you can replace the outside `Frame` of the items in `CollectionView` with `Grid` or `StackLayout` like below:

```
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Cases}" 
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCase}"
                            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                                                       
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 6"
                            Margin="20">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid Padding="2"
                           >
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            
                            <Frame BorderColor="Black"
                                MinimumHeightRequest="40"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                BackgroundColor="{Binding ColorToPrint}">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Id}"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="15"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   />
                            </Frame>
                         
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```